# maximum points detection in a multiple plot MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have 2 FFT spectrums on a plot. I want to get the top 5 maximum points of the overall plot. I get the maximum points separately for each spectrum. How can i combine these spectrums into one and get the overall maximum 5 points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two separate maximum matrix: lets `Max1` and `Max2`
Now combine both of them to form third matrix

```
Max3 = [Matx1 Max2]
```

Sort the Max3 in descending order

```
Max3 = sort(Max3,'descend');
```

Extract the first 5 element

```
peaks = Max3(1:5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the spectra in one vector and sort them in descending order.

```
spec1 = fft(x1); % a spectrum (column vector)
spec2 = fft(x2); % another spectrum (column vector)

dummy = abs([spec1; spec2]); % concatenate absolute values
sorted = sort(dummy, 'descending');

five_greatest = sorted(1:5);
```